# Why would transparency not work in LibGdx on Android 2.3.5?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, textures, libgdx, alpha-transparency

I'm running into trouble with LibGdx developing an 3D Android app. I metioned it briefly in my answer [to my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980702/libgdx-gles2-0-cube-texel-stretching/10993947#10993947), but I have been unable to figure out why I cannot get transparency from .png images.

The textures are transparent, I've checked in my OpenGL3+ framework on windows and they show transparent in the correct parts.

My (simple placeholder) fragment shader code ends with:

```
vec4 finalColor = ambient + diffuse;
finalColor.a = colorMap.a;
gl_FragColor = finalColor;
```

I've tried `finalColor.a = 0.1;` which doesn't work.

I've added this to my code but to no avail:

```
Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);      
Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
```

I've even checked and changed:

```
AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.r = cfg.g = cfg.b = cfg.a = 8;
```

Which I though was the number of bits per channel.

Any help at all on this would be appreciated, I just hope I've not overlooked anything.
It's not a gigantic issue, and I could more or less complete my project without transparency, but would really like to know why I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GL_ALPHA` is not a legal option for `glBlendFunc`. You either want `GL_SRC_ALPHA` (most likely), or `GL_DST_ALPHA`.

`glGetError` would have been helpful to you here, you should start using it!

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glBlendFunc.html

Comment: Thanks so much! Changed to GL_SRC_ALPHA and works as expected, I can't believe I overlooked that. I will try to use `glGetError` more often!